# Magento 2 - Product names with special characters

Tags: magento2, product, mini-cart, special-character

Products having special characters like `TM`, I am importing products using `&trade;` for `TM`, it appears as expected on product detail and listing page. But when the product is added to cart, in mini-cart I see `&trade;` string instead of `TM`.

How can I import or create products with the product name containing special characters in `Magento 2`?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Version: 2.2, Product type: Simple

Comment: Refer this [link](https://github.com/ihor-sviziev/magento2/commit/8a30ffd9ed56f80bb54cbfb597e5452e21e2463c ) , this may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override some file to resolve this:

copy this file in your theme:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

Magento rendering your product name as text `<a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>`. You can change it from `text` to `html` like this `<a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_name"></a>`.

Maybe you are facing same on the checkout page in the summary section you need to do same for that but with this file.

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html
```

From `<strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>` To `<strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="html: $parent.name"></strong>`.